# How to add media.thumbnail to RSS with Yahoo Pipes?

Tags: regex, yahoo-pipes

I create a automatic website and grap content by RSS, I use yahoo pipes to filter the content. Current I got issue, web get media.thumbnail tag on RSS to make featured image but on all of my RSS sources, there are no thumbnail tag.

Normal RSS is

```
<item>
<link>
<title>
<description>
```

So I need to recreate RSS with thumbnail URL. How to add media.thumbnail to current RSS with Yahoo Pipes? My piples URL is http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=6564cf5aa5b34df71484c2b8c379fdf1

I need it look like:

```
<item>
<link>
<title>
<description>
<media.thumbnail>
```

Thank for help

Answer (score 1):

As the last step before the output, add a Loop module.  Inside the loop module, add a string bulider, and build the thumbnail URL in there.  Select "Assign results" and put item.media.thumbnail into the text field.

Comment: can you tell me how to get first image URL of the content and add to item.media.thumbnail field?